# Crop webpage(url) content inside an iframe

Tags: html, css, salesforce, lightning, aura-framework

I have a requirement to embed an url inside iframe, which fits inside a lightning component. I would like to request you all to help me with an approach, where webpage contents can be disabled/cropped so only required consents of page can be viewed inside my iframe. Display: none works, when i use it on webpage using inspect element. But it won't support inside iframe,

Used display:none, it did not result in cropping the webpage.

Comment: Do you control the source of the site that is to be in the iframe?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @A Haworth I have no control over this url. It could be "www.google.com" also.

<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>The iframe element</h1><div style="width: 100%; height: 500px; overflow: hidden; position:relative"><iframe src="https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/" style="position: absolute; left: -300px; top: -50px; width:100%;height:500px"></iframe></div></body></html>